# How to set default selected value for form fields in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

$status = Mage::helper('sliders')->getIsActiveOptionArray();

```
    $fieldset->addField('is_active', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sliders')->__('Status'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'is_active',
            'values'    => $status
    ));
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-to-set-default-value-for-form-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$status = array('-1'=>'Please Select..','1' => 'Option1','2' => 'Option2', '3' => 'Option3')
```